# How can I obtain the System.Type of a type in an external shared assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

I created a shared assembly `MyTypes.dll` that contains a public `FooBar` class type.
I have referenced it in multiple projects and it works as expected.

I have determined its full display name to be: `"MyTypes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=624e4a808e6fc010"`.

I created a new project `NewProject` and added `MyTypes` as a reference.  I would like to determine the members of `FooBar` from within `NewProject` using `System.Type.GetType()`.

Here is what I've written:

```
// NewProject.cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

// namespace... class... method...
Type fb;
fb = Type.GetType("MyTypes.FooBar, MyTypes"); // or the full display name
// Exception will be thrown because fb is set to null
MemberInfo[] fbMembers = fb.GetMembers();
```

However, as noted in the code comments, I cannot provide the correct string format to `GetType` in order to return a valid `Type` for the external assembly.  Also, this approach will work for anything within the current assembly.

**EDIT** Turns out the public key token was missing a digit (copy/paste).

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it where you think it should be).

Comment: If `MyTypes` is referenced, why not just do `typeof(FooBar)`? Also, can you get the assembly via [`Assembly.GetAssembly(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method requires the assembly qualified type name which looks like this:

<Namespace>.<TypeName>, <AssemblyName>, Version=X.X.X.X, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

However, if you've referenced the assembly, you should just be able to use `typeof(FooBar).GetMembers()`.

Comment: As noted in the code comments, I used the "full display name" format as well.  Also, I am well aware of `typeof`; this is entirely for pedagogical purposes.